# Whole word matching with + characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

in MySQL, when searching for a keyword in a text field (devices model) where only "whole word match" is desired, one could use REGEXP and the [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] word-boundary markers:

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]"
```

For example, when we want to find all text fields containing "samsung", using

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]samsung[[:>:]]"
```

However, when the target matching words contains "+ characters", like "samsung s9+" or "samsung s10+", how should I submit a proper query? I tried the following queries but none of them look correct.

1.

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]s9+[[:>:]]"
```

2. 

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP "[[:<:]]s9[+][[:>:]]"
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: You need to escape `+` (special char in regexps).

Comment: Without lookarounds (they are not supported in MySQL versions before 8.0) you can't come up with a generic solution. Either use Tim's suggestion, or this one - `([^[:alnum:]_]|^)s9[+]([^[:alnum:]_]|$)`. Mind it is a workaround and won't work in 100% cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most flavors of SQL, `[[:<:]]s9+[[:>:]]` would be written as `\bs9+\b`.  There are two problems here.  First, `+` is a regex *metacharacter*, and has a special meaning.  It should be escaped with two backslashes.  Also, `\bs9\+\b` would only match if a *word* character follows the `+`, as `+` itself is a `non` word character.  Here is a version which should behave as you expect:

```sql
SELECT name FROM tbl_name WHERE name REGEXP '(^|\\s)s9\\+(\\s|$)';
```

This will match `s9+` when it occurs with either whitespace or the start/end of the input on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative Solution

An alternative would be using the `LIKE` operator in the `WHERE` Clause. For more detailed informations take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp). Here some simple examples:

```
SELECT name 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE name LIKE 's%'
```

This query would return all models, which start with the letter 's'. You could also put the percentage sign before the s. This would return all models, which ends with the letter 's'. Note, that the percentage sign can be placed at every position.

```
SELECT name 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE name LIKE 's___'
```

This query would return all models, which start with the letter 's' and have three letters following after the s. Note, that it will only select the models that have exactly three letters after the 's'.

Answer (score 0):

This is the tip of an iceberg.

When storing part-numbers, product-names, etc, I recommend the following.

- Change the spelling to get rid of spaces, plusses, and other special characters.
- Pad them in some way that avoids changing the 'name'.  (Pad to at least 3 characters -- to help with FULLTEXT searches.)

Do that transformation *before* storing the code into a `FULLTEXT`-indexed column.  Also transform queries that you will feed to `MATCH..AGAINST`.

That way, you can safely and swiftly locate even items that would otherwise be hard to lookup.

Comment: Thanks, Rick for the insight, if I would like to do this, base on my case, what will be your approach, and may I ask if you have any example that I can take as a reference?

Comment: Sorry, this design concept is only beginning to formulate in my noggin.  Give me a list of 30 or so naughty model names; maybe I can flesh out my thoughts further.